# How can I delete all my existing trackbacks?

Tags: spam, pingbacks

I'm sorting out a long-neglected wordpress.org blog. It has over 100,000 pieces of trackback spam. How can I remove them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this more WP-ish:

```
function wpse_delete_trackbacks()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
        "
            DELETE FROM %s WHERE `comment_type` = 'trackback'
        ",
        "{$wpdb->prefix}comments"
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Your quotes around `trackback` need fixing, it's too minor an edit for me to perform!

Comment: @fredley »it's too minor an edit for me to perform« = ??

Comment: I don't have edit privileges, so my edits need to be at least 6 chars :-)

Comment: Ah, ok. You could simply add a comment `// Make the query safer: Use prepare` ;) Or you could add a check if there´re any trackbacks and in this case, abort and output a message. Anyway: fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on finding an elegant solution and just used a MySQL sledgehammer to banish the spam:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_type`="trackback"
```